# Center Text In A Wizard H1 Tag

Tags: html, css, asp.net, text-align

this should be straightforward, but I am missing it.  I am attempting to center the text in my wizard h1 tag, by using this css in my stylesheet.css

```
.h1textalign { text-align:center; }
```

And I am attempting to apply this class like so:

```
<asp:Wizard ID="FirstwzSetup" runat="server" CssClass="wizpad" Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="20px" Style="width: 100%; overflow: scroll;" ActiveStepIndex="0">
    <WizardSteps>
        <asp:WizardStep runat="server" StepType="Start" title="Sponsor Recognition">
           <h1 id="h1test" runat="server" class="h1textalign">Test To Center Text</h1>
        </asp:WizardStep>
    </WizardSteps>
</asp:Wizard>
```

What is stopping the css class from being applied to the h1 tag?

**EDIT**
This is a fiddle with an example - my text is not being centered

https://jsfiddle.net/8e8yo28q/

Comment: An h1 is naturally a block level element so that should work. Is there other css that's being applied to it that's preventing the `text-align: center;`? For example, if it has `display: inline-block;` applied to it for some unknown reason, then it won't center.

Comment: Your text is centered in the h1. The h1 being 200px wide. If you want to center the h1 itself, you could use `margin: 0 auto;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since header is a block element, you may need to give it a width as well.  Also, you can apply the important tag to ensure no other css settings are causing your issue.

```
    h1 {width: 100%; text-align:center !important;}
```

Comment: Yes!  Sorry.  The Width should be 100% not 200px

Answer (score 0):

Just add `width:100%` to your `h1` tag

Try adding `border:1px solid black`, to your previous css, and you will notice that your `h1` is restricted to certain width.

If you add `%` width to it, i.e `100%`, it will take the relative width of the parent.

And your text in `h1` will center itself.

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f7fqn9nm/)